# Mod-rewrite trailing slash and additional $GET

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I need a little help with some mod_rewrite syntax, currently I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Which display mydomain.com/index.php?page=testpage when a user goes to mydomain.com/testpage.

There are two more things I want to do but playing around with other examples haven't be able to do so far.

Firstly, I want to make mydomain.com/testpage/ to work just like mydomain.com/testpage works whereby the trailing slash has no effect on functionality.

Secondly, I want to add a second variable that may not always be present so that mydomain.com/testpage/testvar will display mydomain.com/index.php?page=testpage&var=testvar

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional rule and make trailing slash optional:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&var=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you it works, however when adding a trailing slash it does cause my page formatting (which is reliant on bootstrap) to become non existant, any quick fix for that?

Comment: That is due to your use of relative links in css/js/images. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`